# Use Qt in specialized domain library?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I want to use Qt to develop a GUI for my specialized application. I opened two projects: one is called "Gui" executible with all Gui-related code by using Qt, the other is called "Core" library with specialized-domain-related code. In my project "Core", I have many functions like

```
bool DoSomething(ArgumentTypes arguments, string& errorInfo);
```

If DoSomething failed, I can get some meaningful error information. I want to show this error information in the GUI (such as in message box) and can be translated to other languages by Qt translation feature. May I need to build a Qt library for my "Core" library and then use QString and tr() functions to implement what I want? It seems using Qt for my "Core" library is not proper since it is not GUI. Any good ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my diploma thesis, I wrote a program that linked QtCore and ran on a headless supercomputer. I mostly used QtCore for string handling and plugin loading, also the geometric primitives (QPoint, QLine, etc.).

As you see, Qt is not per-se a GUI library. If you like, you can think of Qt as a development platform. The coherent swiss-army-knife framework that standard C++ lacks. Qt is a large framework, with GUI being only one of the facets.

So I recommend that you link your core library against QtCore, and your GUI application against QtCore+QtGui (+ more Qt modules as needed).